# ServerScriptService.Script:5: attempt to index nil with 'CFrame'"

Tags: lua, roblox

```lua
local TeleportEvent = game.ReplicatedStorage.TeleportEvent



TeleportEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(Player,Position)
    



    local TeleportPoint = game.Workspace.TeleportPoints:FindFirstChild(Position)
    



    Player.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = TeleportPoint.CFrame
end)
```

And it says in the output,"ServerScriptService.Script:5: attempt to index nil with 'CFrame'"

I was trying to teleport someone somewhere with GUI, to teleport someone to a block, and I was expecting to teleport there.

Answer (score 0):

I think `FindFirstChild` isn't finding anything so it returns `nil`. Are you sure that `Position` is a string. I suggest adding

```
print(Position)
```

so you can make sure that `Position` is the correct name of a part in `TeleportPoints`.